# use momentjs to check if this time range is conflict with other time range

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Scenario 1

```
Time range 1 : 2016-12-06 11:00 to 2016-12-06 12:00
Time range 2 : 2016-12-06 10:00 to 2016-12-06 13:00
time range 1 is completely conflict with time range 2 and vice versa
```

Scenario 2

```
Time range 1 : 2016-12-06 11:00 to 2016-12-06 12:00
Time range 2 : 2016-12-06 11:00 to 2016-12-06 14:00
time range 1 is partial conflict with time range 2 and vice versa
```

Scenario 3

```
Time range 1 : 2016-12-06 11:00 to 2016-12-06 12:00
Time range 2 : 2016-12-06 09:00 to 2016-12-06 12:00
time range 1 is partial conflict with time range 2 and vice versa
```

How to accomplish above scenario using momentjs? I tried the `isBetween` function but couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think [moment-range](https://github.com/gf3/moment-range) is what you are looking for. Use its `overlaps` and `contains` function to make it. You can link to moment-range from the [cdnjs servers](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/moment-range).

```
var date1 = [moment("2016-12-06 11:00"), moment("2016-12-06 12:00")];
var date2 = [moment("2016-12-06 10:00"), moment("2016-12-06 13:00")];

var range  = moment.range(date1);
var range2 = moment.range(date2);

// has overlapping
if(range.overlaps(range2)) {
    if((range2.contains(range, true) || range.contains(range2, true)) && !date1[0].isSame(date2[0]))
    alert("time range 1 is completely conflict with time range 2 and vice versa");
  else
    alert("time range 1 is partially conflict with time range 2 and vice versa");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isBetween and test the scenario by calculating the weight of the conflict.

```
function testDate(d1, d2) {
  // d1 and d2 in array format
  // [moment from, moment to]
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0, t; t = d1[i]; i++) {
    // use isBetween exclusion
    if (t.isBetween(d2[0], d2[1], null, '()')) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0, t; t = d2[i]; i++) {
    // use isBetween exclusion
    if (t.isBetween(d1[0], d1[1], null, '()')) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  if (count > 1) {
    return console.log('completely conflict');
  }

  if (count > 0) {
    return console.log('partial conflict');
  }

  return console.log('something else');
}

var time1 = [moment('2016-12-06 11:00'), moment('2016-12-06 12:00')];
var time2 = [moment('2016-12-06 10:00'), moment('2016-12-06 13:00')];
var time3 = [moment('2016-12-06 11:00'), moment('2016-12-06 12:00')];
var time4 = [moment('2016-12-06 11:00'), moment('2016-12-06 14:00')];
var time5 = [moment('2016-12-06 11:00'), moment('2016-12-06 12:00')];
var time6 = [moment('2016-12-06 09:00'), moment('2016-12-06 12:00')];
testDate(time1, time2); // completely conflict
testDate(time3, time4); // partial conflict
testDate(time5, time6); // partial conflict
```