# Check if date is conflict on a range of dates on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, momentjs

I am creating a simple calendar with appointments. 
I have documents with the date ranges example below.

```
{
"start_date" : "2020-02-06T19:58:25.430Z",
"end_date" : "2020-02-16T19:58:25.430Z"
},
{
"start_date" : "2020-02-17T19:58:25.430Z",
"end_date" : "2020-02-27T19:58:25.430Z"
},
{
"start_date" : "2020-03-21T19:58:25.430Z",
"end_date" : "2020-03-31T19:58:25.430Z"
},
```

If user entered start_date and end_date that has conflict on already created date range, system should prevent the user to insert new document.

How can I do it? can I use Moment JS?

Comment: You can search conflicted appointment from your Node.JS code and prevent new event insertions on conflict.

Comment: I used now the moment-range package. I found it on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970369/use-momentjs-to-check-if-this-time-range-is-conflict-with-other-time-range

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique compound index:

```
db.collection.createIndex({'start_date':1, 'end_date': 1}, {'unique': true})
```

Comment: Using this, if user provide date like "2020-03-19..." to "2020-03-22", will it detect a conflict from date range, 2020-03-21 to 2020-03-31" document on index 2?